# ImportError: No module named rospkg Reinstalled still not work

Tags: ros, rospkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed the simulation environment of [Nao Players in RobCup](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_virtual).
Everything is okay but cannot find Rospkg. I reinstalled with many methods but still not work. In fact, the pkg is there exactly and if I import `rospkg` in python client, the error occurs. I wonder if there is some problem about Python. Hope someone can help me. Thank you very much

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
    import xacro
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from roslaunch import substitution_args
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import rospkg

**ImportError: No module named rospkg**

while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/nao_description/launch/upload_nao.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py /opt/ros/indigo/share/nao_description/urdf/naoV40_generated_urdf/nao_robot.xacro] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find nao_description)/urdf/nao$(arg version)_generated_urdf/nao_robot.xacro" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221355/importerror:-no-module-named-rospkg-reinstalled-still-not-work/) by [Robert Delong](https://answers.ros.org/users/25156/robert-delong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2015-11-23**:
How you are installing rospkg? sudo apt-get install python-rospkg or with sudo pip install -U rospkg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out the reason. Because i installed 'conda', the bad guy change the env path of python. The sys cannot access the package. I delete it and make the pkg work. Thank you very much. In fact, I meet a even sever problem now. I will post it tomorrow since it is too late now. Here is mid-night,hah

---

Originally posted by [Robert Delong](https://answers.ros.org/users/25156/robert-delong/) with karma: 11 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmed Abdalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/25274/ahmed-abdalla/) on 2016-06-05**:
How can we fix it without removing conda?
I'm working on a project that needs it.